# Crashing Issue On IOS 8.X And Android 5 Using Rhodes

Tags: ios8, android-5.0-lollipop, rhomobile, rhodes, ios8.1

We have an Issue on IOS/Android Devices.

Our application crash on iPhone/iPad that used IOS 8 and IOS 8.1 and Android 5.

We used:

- Rhodes 4.0.0
- RhoElements 4.0.0

Any Advice ?

**Update:**

here is the rholog.txt and crash report from IOS.

[Files on DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l84po6wh761ypuf/log%26Crash.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rhodes v4.0.0 was released September/October 2013, around iOS7 release dates.
Newer version of RhoMobile Suite/Rhodes are now available that better support iOS8.

[Rhodes 5.0sp2-stable branch on github](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes/tree/5-0-sp2-stable) supports iOS8 and iPhone6 and a RhoMobile Suite v5.0 Service Pack 1 built around this version should be released shortly.

More than this, without an understanding of which issues you're encountering, it's impossible to help.